# Pass variables in AngularJS $http GET?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, webapp2

Is it possible to pass a variable to a server in AngularJS $http service GET? I want to be able to "GET" a certain number of items from the server, and in the request I want to specify the number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just add it onto the url:

```
$http.get("/users?items=15").success(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
});
```

Then in your python handler for **/users** get the value of **items** `using self.request.get("items")`